# Trying to return an address of a local variable in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I want to return the address of variable `k` in function `func()`. Here is are the 2 functions.

> **main()** Function

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int* j;
  int* func();

  j= func();
  printf("\n%d",*j);
}
```

> **func()** Function

```
int* func()
{
  static int k=30;
  return (&k);
}
```

I wanted `int *func()` to return the address of `k`, but following error was displayed.

`function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]`

`return (&k);`

Comment: The life of `k` ends when the function returns. What are you going to do with the address of something that no longer exists? Also, what's with `main()`?

Comment: Huh? Now the code has a `static int k;`, which I guess it didn't have originally and which changes things completely. Very confusing.

Comment: Yes I edited it. I am sorry completely my mistake. @unwind

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing out my mistakes and helping me mending them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k` is a local variable who exists only inside the function `func`.
So you are returning the address where `k` does not exist.
It is `undefined behavior`.

You could allocate dynamic memory for `k`:

```
int *k = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));  
*k = 30
return k;
```

Do not forget to free the memory in your `main`

```
free(j);
```

Comment: What happens on making the variable `k` static?

Comment: Then `k` exists as long as the program is alive. You can return address of static variable also.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error, it's a warning. Still you should not do it because as soon as a local variable goes out of scope (like in the case of a return) it logically seizes to exist and should not be used at the penalty of unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: What if I make variable `k` static. What happens than?

Comment: Then it becomes a global visibility limited and **not** a scope-local variable. In that case it's perfectly valid code, not quite sure what you want to achieve though.

Comment: When you make k static, it places it in the same area that global variables live.  It'll give you what you want to achieve, but allocating the memory, passing a pointer in from the calling function, or other such solutions are far better.

Comment: I just want to return the address of variable `k` from `func()` to `main()`.

Comment: @VSP If thats what you want then your code fulfils that. The compiler just warns you that should should not dereference that pointer as it points to memory which has already been recycled.

Comment: @SergeyL. Could you please elaborate your word, when you said "Then it becomes a global visibility limited and not a scope-local variable". I am rookie, so please bear with me on this one.

Comment: @VSP `static` variables that are declared within functions are global and persistent between function calls just like any regular global variable. The only difference is that their visibility (being accessed by their variable name) is limited to the function scope that declares them.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 int* func()
 {
   static int k=30;
   return &k;
 }
```

Comment: This looks like trial and error. Hey, just try something else. It makes the warning disappear so it must be what you want.