# Not able to find my segmentation fault in this code of t-test

Tags: c, function, statistics, segmentation-fault

I have written this program for t-test. I'll add other functions as well, but first, I need to find my error. Here's my code

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>

float mean(float x[], int size)
{
  float sum = 0.0;
  for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
    sum += x[i];
  return sum/size;
}

float sumsq(float x[], int size)
{
  float sum = 0.0;
  for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
    sum += pow(x[i]-mean(x,size),2);
  return sum;
}

int input(n)
{
  
  float x[n];
  printf("Enter the values one by one");
  for (int i = 0; i<n;i++)
    scanf("%f", &x[i]);
  return x;
}

void t_check(float x)// Make sure to write this function before each of the t-tests. That is because it is of void type. If the t-test is done before the checking function is declared, then it assumes it's datatype to be "int", and we get an error. So either write the t-check function before those functions, or just define it at the beginning of the program
{
  float t_tab;
  printf("Enter the tabulated value of t");
  scanf("%f",&t_tab);
  if (x<t_tab)
    printf("We do not have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis");
  else
    printf("Reject the null hypothesis");
}


float t_diff_of_means()
{
  float x=0.0,y=0.0,s1=0.0,s2=0.0,S=0.0,t=0.0,tcal;
  int n,m,a,b;
  printf("Enter the number of variables in population 1");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  a = input(n);
  printf("Enter the number of variables in population 2");
  scanf("%d", &m);
  b = input(m);
  x = mean(a,n);
  y = mean(b,m);
  s1 = sumsq(a, n);
  s2 = sumsq(b, m);
  S  = sqrt((s1+s2)/(n+m-2));
  t = (x-y)/(S*sqrt(1.0/n+1.0/m));
  t_check(t);
}


int main(void) 
{
  t_diff_of_means();
  return 0;
}
```

It gives segmentation fault as an error. I'm not able to understand where my code uses any memory uses a part of memory that is not allocated to it

Comment: Does your compiler mention something about returning address of local variable? `return x;` That is illegal. Look up for scope and lifetime of variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to return an address of a local variable in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285127/trying-to-return-an-address-of-a-local-variable-in-a-function)

Comment: Anyway, `int input(n)` is the wrong type to `return x;` and the compiler would mention that. I got a dozen compiler warnings, please fix them all before even running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The main issue is you expect `input()` to read an array floats but you return an `int`.  You should declare the type of the argument `n`.  You cannot return an address to a local variable as it out of scope for caller.  The easiest option is to the declare the array variable in `main()` then pass it to input to populate (pun).  (not fixed) Check that return value of `scanf()` otherwise the variable you expect to be initialized may not be.
2. `t_diff_of_means()` is declared to return a `float` but nothing is returned.  Not sure what you want to return so I changed the return type to `void`.
3. Tweaked various prompts to make it more them more readable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float mean(float x[], int size)
{
    float sum = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
        sum += x[i];
    return sum/size;
}

float sumsq(float x[], int size)
{
    float sum = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
        sum += pow(x[i]-mean(x,size),2);
    return sum;
}

void input(size_t n, float a[n])
{
    printf("Enter the values one by one: ");
    for (int i = 0; i<n;i++)
        scanf("%f", a+i);
}

void t_check(float x)
{
    float t_tab;
    printf("Enter the tabulated value of t: ");
    scanf("%f",&t_tab);
    if (x<t_tab)
        printf("We do not have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis\n");
    else
        printf("Reject the null hypothesis\n");
}


void t_diff_of_means()
{
    float x=0.0,y=0.0,s1=0.0,s2=0.0,S=0.0,t=0.0;
    int n,m;
    printf("Enter the number of variables in population 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    float a[n];
    input(n, a);
    printf("Enter the number of variables in population 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    float b[m];
    input(m, b);
    x = mean(a,n);
    y = mean(b,m);
    s1 = sumsq(a, n);
    s2 = sumsq(b, m);
    S  = sqrt((s1+s2)/(n+m-2));
    t = (x-y)/(S*sqrt(1.0/n+1.0/m));
    t_check(t);
}


int main(void)
{
    t_diff_of_means();
    return 0;
}
```

and example run:

```
Enter the number of variables in population 1: 2 
Enter the values one by one: 1
2
Enter the number of variables in population 2: 2
Enter the values one by one: 2
3
Enter the tabulated value of t: 0.05
We do not have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis
```

Consider eliminating the variables you only use once (x, y, s1, s2, S, t and t_cal):

```
    t_check(
        (mean(a, n) - mean(b, m)) / (sqrt((sumsq(a, n)+sumsq(b, m))/(n+m-2))*sqrt(1.0/n+1.0/m))
    );
```

then I observed that this only depends on variables `a`, `n`, `b` and `m` so push that calculation into `t_check()`:

```
void t_check(size_t a_len, float a[a_len], size_t b_len, float b[b_len]) {
    float t = (mean(a, a_len) - mean(b, b_len)) / (sqrt((sumsq(a, a_len)+sumsq(b, b_len))/(a_len+b_len-2))*sqrt(1.0/a_len+1.0/b_len));
    // ...
}
```

Then I changed the length types to `size_t` and used the clearer variable names in `t_diff_of_means()`:

```
void t_diff_of_means()
{
    printf("Enter the number of variables in population 1: ");
    size_t a_len;
    scanf("%zu", &a_len);
    float a[a_len];
    input(a_len, a);

    printf("Enter the number of variables in population 2: ");
    size_t b_len;
    scanf("%zu", &b_len);
    float b[b_len];
    input(b_len, b);

    t_check(a_len, a, b_len, b);
}
```

We could take this another step by observing the two first sections in `t_diff_of_means()` are very similar, so we could have `input()` take a prompt and a pointer to an array of floats along with elements read.  `input()` would then need to dynamically allocate the array of floats.  This means most of our functions take a array of float and length argument.  Let's create a type for that and refactor our functions to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct array {
    size_t len;
    float *data;
};

float mean(struct array *a)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<a->len;i++)
        sum += a->data[i];
    return sum/a->len;
}

float sumsq(struct array *a)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<a->len;i++)
        sum += pow(a->data[i] - mean(a), 2);
    return sum;
}

void input(int prompt, struct array *a)
{
    printf("Enter the number of variables in population %d: ", prompt);
    scanf("%zu", &a->len);
    a->data = malloc(a->len * sizeof(a->data[0]));
    //if(!a->data) ...
    printf("Enter the values one by one: ");
    for (int i = 0; i<a->len;i++)
        scanf("%f", &a->data[i]);
}

void t_check(struct array a[2])
{
    float t = (mean(a) - mean(a+1)) / (
        sqrt(
            (sumsq(a) + sumsq(a+1)) / (a[0].len + a[1].len-2)
        ) * sqrt(1.0/a[0].len + 1.0/a[1].len)
    );
    printf("Enter the tabulated value of t: ");
    float t_tab;
    scanf("%f",&t_tab);
    if (t<t_tab)
        printf("We do not have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis\n");
    else
        printf("Reject the null hypothesis\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    struct array a[2];
    input(1, a);
    input(2, a+1);
    t_check(a);
}
```

This would be a good base to add additional functions to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try implementing them.  Although I don't understand one thing, in the input function, while populating the array, why did you use scanf("%f", a+i); and not scanf("%f", &a[i]);

Comment: @AnweshanGoswami It means exactly the same thing.  See the pointer vs array notation.